# Can I mount a 60" TV and mount weighing a combined 95 pounds to a drywall or plaster?

Tags: drywall, mounting, studs, lath-and-plaster, television

I cannot find studs on my firewall but, when I drilled a hole on the wall, it seems to me that either the plaster or drywall was thick enough (like 1/2"). Can I Mount a 60" TV and Mount Weighing a Combined 95 pounds to that Drywall or Plaster?

Comment: No. That's a lot of weight for plaster/drywall.

Comment: How are you trying to find studs?  Stud finder?  Knock method? When you say fire wall, what do you mean?  An actual firewall that prevents the spread of a fire or do you mean the wall your fireplace is on?  Age of home, that will give you a clue if you have drywall or plaster?  If you have plaster, you typically need a higher end stud finder to find the studs.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the studs, I know you can!  Here is a link to many helpful tips: http://www.bobvila.com/articles/how-to-find-a-wall-stud/ but the short version is, measure from the corner of the room (there will be a stud within 1" of each corner of the room and look for the stud on a 16" spacing (unless your home/condo/apt is really old).  Drill a few pilot holes (in the region of the bracket) until you have found a stud, and if that doesn't work then try some of Bob's additional sleuth tips.  Once you hit one, drill a few more small holes a half inch apart to make sure you know exactly where it is and are close to the center of the stud when putting in the bolts for the bracket.

Don't worry about putting extra holes all over that section of the wall, installing the bracket will cover it and if you do go to remove it you will probably wreck most of the sheetrock (the mount will glue itself to the paint on the wall) so you will have a patch job on your hands no matter how careful you are during installation.